# trying to log into facebook using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I just started toying with VBA about a week ago. I can open IE and get to facebook. I can even enter my email in the right slot(because the cursor is already selected that spot). I cant seem to find a way to select the password field to enter my password. Let alone hit the log in button. Please help

here is my code so far

```
Sub facebookPost()

    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.Application")
    IE.Navigate ("www.Facebook.com")
    IE.Visible = True

    Do While IE.Busy
      DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

    IE.Document.all.Item("email").Value = "*******"
    IE.Document.all.Item("pass").Value = "********"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the source of the button

`<label class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm" id="loginbutton" for="u_0_4"><input value="Log in" tabindex="4" id="u_0_4" type="submit"></label>`

This works for me

```
IE.Document.all.Item("loginbutton").Click
```

So your code looks like this

```
Sub facebookPost()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim sUser As String, sPass As String

    '~~> Change as Applicable
    sUser = "Blah Blah"
    sPass = "Blah Blah"

    Set IE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.Application")

    IE.Navigate ("www.Facebook.com")
    IE.Visible = True

    Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

    IE.Document.all.Item("email").Value = sUser
    IE.Document.all.Item("pass").Value = sPass
    IE.Document.all.Item("loginbutton").Click
End Sub
```

Comment: i copied your code exactly. replaced the blah blah with my info. still nothing.

Comment: Then is there any other reason it wouldn't be working for me?

Comment: IE.Document.all.Item("email").Value = sUser

Comment: run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108':

automation error
the object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Comment: I copy/pasted. replaced the sUser = "Blah Blah"/sPass = "Blah Blah" with my own information, and deleted '~~> Change as Applicable.

Comment: Oh wait. Try these two things. Open IE and open facebook manually. I am guessing that you are already logged in. If yes, then log out and try again. And if you are not logged in then close all ie instances and try again. Ensure that you do not have any instance in task manager as well.

Comment: i must have had IE running in the background this whole time. i ended the task and it worked perfect. thanks a lot

Comment: @TimothyHall please consider accepting this answer if it helped you as it will then help others. (You'll also get a little rep for doing so!)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loginbutton just write login and it works for me